# Prove linear independence of a set of functions

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a set of functions $$S = \{x, e^{z_1 x}, \ldots, e^{z_n x}\},$$ with $z_i \in \mathbb{C}$, how to prove the linear independence of this set for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian Of course, the $z_i$ will need to be pairwise distinct for $S$ to be linearly independent.

Comment: ad absurdum: suppose there is a linear combination of those function that equals 0 (i.e. the null function on $\mathbb{R}$), and apply that formula for various x...

Comment: What about various Fourier/Laplace-like transforms which allow us to represent $x$ in terms of a linear combinations of exponentials?

Comment: Linear independence...over $\;\Bbb C\;$or over $\;\Bbb R\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio $x$ is taken to be real and $z_i$ are complex.

Comment: @LBO That I understood already, but that $\;S\;$ doesn't stand, or at least *shouldn't* stand, by itself: you are taking it as a set of vectors... **where**? In a complex or in a real linear space of functions

Comment: @DonAntonio Sorry, let's make the underlying field $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you meant to say it when $z_i$ are all distinct.

Say the given set of functions are linearly dependent.

So $a_0x+a_1e^{z_1x}+a_2e^{z_2x}+\dots +a_ne^{z_nx}=0$ and $a_i\neq0$ for some $i$. $\dots (1)$

W.l.o.g assume that $|z_1|<|z_2|<\dots <|z_n|$.

Say the largest $i$ for which $a_i\neq 0$ be equal to $k$.

Now divide both sides of $(1)$ by $e^{z_kx}$.

Now we can find a sequence $\{x_n\}$ going to $\infty$ and norm of $e^{z_ix_n}/e^{z_kx_n}$ goes to $0$ for all $i<k$. (Think of it by explicitly writing down the norm of $e^{zx}$)

Now $||a_0x/e^{z_kx}+a_1e^{z_1x}/e^{z_kx}+a_2e^{z_2x}/e^{z_kx}+\dots +a_k||>(||a_k||-||a_0x/e^{z_kx}+a_1e^{z_1x}/e^{z_kx}+a_2e^{z_2x}/e^{z_kx}||)$

And we can make $||a_0x/e^{z_kx}+a_1e^{z_1x}/e^{z_kx}+a_2e^{z_2x}/e^{z_kx}||$ arbitarily small by taking the sequence $x_n$, hence there exists an $x$ such that $||a_0x/e^{z_kx}+a_1e^{z_1x}/e^{z_kx}+a_2e^{z_2x}/e^{z_kx}+\dots +a_k||\neq 0$ (A contradiction to the linear dependency).

Note that the result is true w.rt both the fields $\mathbb{R}$ and  $\mathbb{C}$.